# nodejs memorystream to download file

Tags: node.js

I'm wondering if stream could be piped multiple times? According to the document, I don't see any direct answer, here is my code sample.

```
var request = require('request');
var MemoryStream = require('memorystream');

var download = (options, stream) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options).pipe(stream).on('finish', () => {
      resolve();
    }).on('error', error => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
};

(async () => {
  let stream = new MemoryStream(null, {
    readable: true,
    writable: true
  });
  let total = 8000, block = 3000;// will fetch by HEAD method
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    let from = i * block;
    let to = Math.min(total - 1, from + block - 1);
    await download({
      url: 'https://www.website.com/logo.png',
      headers: {
        'Range': 'bytes=' + from + '-' + to
      }
    }, stream);
    console.log(i + ' done');
  }
})();
```

Output is like "0 0 done 1", then nothing will happen, no error, so I guess I'm using the memorystream wrong way?

Comment: What is the use-case here? Do you want to provide a progress bar for the download? In that case, you could use event streaming instead of pipe.